# How can I send an "offline" message from Service Worker?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

How do i return the cache, with an message saying offline. Is it possbile?

code I have so far just sends back the cache:

```
const cachedFetch = request => request.method != 'GET' ? 

  fetch(request) : 
  caches.open("demo").then(cache =>
    cache.match(request).then(resp => {
      if(!!resp) {
        console.log('cache', request.url)
        return resp;// how to send custom message back with resp
      } else {
        console.log('not in cache', request.url)
        return fetch(request).then(response => {
         return response


        })
      }
    })
  )

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => event.respondWith(
    cachedFetch(event.request)
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Service Worker can use [`postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Client/postMessage) to notify the client. Alternatively, the app can also listen for online/offline events independently of the Service Worker:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/Online_and_offline_events